# How to store each data that has been calculate based on date and no plan in table that create in php code to display

Tags: php, mysql

Someone can I ask some help for my system. I have some problems to store the calculation data for each date into table that I construct. The problem are when first date data has been calculate it store at the first column but when the second date data calculate it total all my calculation into only one column. For Example : start date 04-09-2020 and end 05-09-2020  it will be like this :

This code for this part :

```
 if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"])) {  
   
   $day =date("d", strtotime($_POST["from_date"]));
   $end =date("d", strtotime($_POST["to_date"]));
 

      ?><table class="table table-bordered">  
         <tr> 
            <th width="10%">Date testing 2</th> <?php
            for($i=$day; $i<=$end; $i++){ 

               ?><th width="10%"><?php echo $i?></th><?php
            }
            ?>
            <th width="10%">Total</th>
            <th width="10%">Balance To Go</th>
         </tr> <?php

   if(mysqli_num_rows($resultR) > 0){

      if(isset($_POST["FighterID"]) and !empty($_POST["FighterID"])){
        /..../
      }else{
         
         // second table
         while($rowF = $resultX -> fetch_assoc()){// registerfighter
            
            $totalPlus = 0;
            //table start
            ?> <tr> 
                  <td><?php echo 'ID = '.$rowF["UserID"] ?></td>  
            <?php
 
            $resultR -> data_seek(0);
            while($rowR = $resultR -> fetch_assoc()){// by record

               $resultY-> data_seek(0);
               while($rowY = $resultY -> fetch_assoc()){// by addplan 

                  if( ($rowF["UserID"]===$rowR["UserIDD"])  and ( ($rowR["No_Plan"]) !== '1' and ($rowY["No_Plan"] === $rowR['No_Plan']) ) ){
                     
                     $total =  ($rowR["UserInputNEW"] + $rowR["UserInputNMP"]);
                     $totalPlus = $totalPlus + $total;       
                     /*?><td> <?php echo '';?></td> <?php*/
                  }
               }
            }
         
            ?> 
                  <td><?php echo 'Totaling  A8 / RP8 = '.$totalPlus; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo 'Total  A8 / RP8 = '.$totalPlus; ?></td>
                  <td><?php echo 'Balance  A8 / RP8 = '.( 40 - $totalPlus); ?></td> 
               </tr> 
            <?php
            //table end
         }
      }
```

problems[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i16Uo.png)
suppose[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltLyj.png)

Comment: I would guess that 80% of contributors to this forum are self-studiers!

Answer (score 0):

You should print the individual calculations inside the while loop and the total calculations outside the while loop. Try this

```
if(isset($_POST["from_date"], $_POST["to_date"])) {  
   
   $day =date("d", strtotime($_POST["from_date"]));
   $end =date("d", strtotime($_POST["to_date"]));
 

      ?><table class="table table-bordered">  
         <tr> 
            <th width="10%">Date testing 2</th> <?php
            for($i=$day; $i<=$end; $i++){ 

               ?><th width="10%"><?php echo $i?></th><?php
            }
            ?>
            <th width="10%">Total</th>
            <th width="10%">Balance To Go</th>
         </tr> <?php

   if(mysqli_num_rows($resultR) > 0){

      if(isset($_POST["FighterID"]) and !empty($_POST["FighterID"])){
        /..../
      }else{
         
         // second table
         while($rowF = $resultX -> fetch_assoc()){// registerfighter
            
            $totalPlus = 0;
            //table start
            ?> <tr> 
                  <td><?php echo 'ID = '.$rowF["UserID"] ?></td>  
            <?php
 
            $resultR -> data_seek(0);
            while($rowR = $resultR -> fetch_assoc()){// by record

               $resultY-> data_seek(0);
               while($rowY = $resultY -> fetch_assoc()){// by addplan 

                  if( ($rowF["UserID"]===$rowR["UserIDD"])  and ( ($rowR["No_Plan"]) !== '1' and ($rowY["No_Plan"] === $rowR['No_Plan']) ) ){
                     
                     $total =  ($rowR["UserInputNEW"] + $rowR["UserInputNMP"]);
                     $totalPlus = $totalPlus + $total;       
                     echo "<td>Totaling  A8 / RP8 = ".$totalPlus."</td>";
                  }
               }
            }
         
            ?> 
                <td><?php echo 'Balance  A8 / RP8 = '.( 40 - $totalPlus); ?></td> 
               </tr> 
            <?php
            //table end
         }
      }
```